# How did "fixing" the villains prevent them from dying in Spider-Man: No Way Home?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, Peter does not want to send the villains back to their universes to die. He wants to "fix" them (cure them). It was implied that would keep them from dying, but how? Was this explained?

Comment: No clue. Especially considering the fact that, while they've been trapped in that basement, they concluded that all of them have been in their "dying scenes" when they suddenly came into this "new Spiderman verse". There is another nonsensical or "inexplicable" notion, f.e. how can Doc Octopus and the Green Goblin be there at the same time? They are from the same Metaverse, and Octo-Doc states multiple times that Osbourne is dead. Maybe one of the rocket scientists out there will figure this one out Until then it just looks like Marvel doesn't care about conclusive storytelling anymore.

Comment: @Johannes though Green Goblin may be in the same universe, there is a possibility that one / both of the characters exist in different universes as well, so are *actually* from different universes...

Comment: @taylor.2317 that would mean that virtually any nanosecond in any "universe" could produce a Green Goblin in this Spiderman's universe, i.e. he'd be fighting billions of Green Goblins from "Tobey Maguire's Spiderman universe" at the same time. That's why they chose the "dying scenes" as exit and entrance points from one metaverse into the other. The writers needed at least a bit of "story-telling-conclusiveness" in order to explain the metaverse-stuff to the audience. But as the OP pointed out: How does healing them changes the outcome of their "dying scenes" then?

Comment: @Johannes: "There is another nonsensical or "inexplicable" notion, f.e. how can Doc Octopus and the Green Goblin be there at the same time? They are from the same Metaverse, and Octo-Doc states multiple times that Osbourne is dead." – I think Peter 2 and Peter 3 both mention that those villains had already died in the past, relative to the moment the Peters were plucked out of their respective universes... But see my comment on the top answer for how to reconcile that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it was explained in [this dialogue](https://movies.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_No_Way_Home/Transcript) between Peter Parker and the villains while Doctor Strange has them all incarcerated:

> Otto Octavius: You could've just left us to die. Why didn't you?
>
> MJ: Because that's not who he is.
>
> Peter Parker: I think I can help you guys. If I can **fix what happened to you, then when you go back, things will be different and you might not die fighting Spider-Man.**
>
> [...]
>
> Peter Parker: **I can't promise you guys anything, but at least this way, you actually get to go home and have a chance. A second chance. I mean, come on. Isn't that worth trying?**
>
> Curt Connors: Trust me, Peter... When you try to fix people, there are always consequences.
>
> Peter Parker: I mean, you don't have to come. I also didn't know that you could talk. [The Lizard growls in disapproval] But if you stay here... you're gonna have to deal with the wizard.
>
> Curt Connors: So, we go along, or die. Not much of a choice, is it?
>
> Flint Marko: I just wanna go home.
>
> Max Dillon: Well, I myself don't wanna be killed, especially by a guy dressed like Dungeons & Dragons, so... what's your plan?
>
> Peter Parker: I have it all under control.

'Fixing' the villains will give them a second chance at life, helping them avoid the choices that will ultimately lead to each dying fighting 'their' Spiderman.

Comment: Your answer is correct even though the movie is weak in this regard. If the villains were not plucked from moments before their death, it seems more reasonable. But why would Peter 2 & 3 be there long after the deaths of the villains, yet the villains were taken at an arbitrary time? If the villains traveled from right before death, it seems that both other Peters would know this and know "fixing" them would not save their lives... although it might save their souls, and still be worth it? It would seem safest to keep the fixed reformed villains in Peter's universe (and kinda interesting).

Comment: @John: Based on the MCU's depiction of the multiverse: Changing (what Peter 2 and Peter 3 perceive as) "the past" via time travel shenanigans creates a branch in the timeline. So in those Peters' timelines, the villains really did die... But for the villains, they don't entirely "go back to their own universe"; rather, the change in their experiences would presumably create a branching timeline when they return (at least, if they go back and do anything differently than they would have otherwise). Time travel and multiverses are confusing :P

Comment: @V2Blast I agree with your idea, it is reasonable (based on what was established in the MCU movies). Of course it was also established by the Ancient One they had one timeline they were keeping (or trying to keep) and one might imagine that Dr Strange would try to keep that as well. That said, I've not seen the recent Dr Strange film, so maybe it's not a concern anymore :)

Answer (score 3):

It was the villains' "defects" that caused them to die: e.g. Green Goblin's alter ego was Norman's last consciousness. Doc Ock's arms were in control, causing him the urge to rebuild the reactor which ultimately made him drown. Electro also was killed, as he went power-heavy and tried to contain the city's power.

These "defects" are what caused the villains' death, and removing them would save them.

Comment: I think the point of contention is the moment the villains were plucked from, which would presumably be the same moment they go back to when they return. If they were plucked from their universes *as they were about to die*... then even if they're changed/better people now, they're still moments from death, and might not have the chance to demonstrate that they've changed (and thus prevent their deaths).